# Binding to code behind throws exception

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have declared a namespace as follows (showing only relevant code)

```
<Page 
     xmlns:local="using:ABC"
 >
```

My page resources are as follows

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <local:Login x:Key="mykey"/>
 </Page.Resources>
```

Here Login is the class inside namespace ABC and this class is my code-behind file called Login.xaml.cs

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="mystackpanel" DataContext="{StaticResource mykey}" >

            <TextBox PlaceholderText="Email or Mobile Number" Text="{Binding Mobile_Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <TextBox PlaceholderText="Password" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <Button Content="Login" Click="LoginButton_Click"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

And My code behind class Login.xaml.cs has two public properties called Mobile_Email and Password.

When I use this in the class constructor

```
mystackpanel.DataContext=this;
```

The binding works but declaring the resource like that in page resources gives me stackoverflow exception.

My question is why I am getting a stackoverflow exception and how do I bind my stackpanel in xaml with the code behind class Login

Comment: Post the code that declares your two properties

Comment: There is no problem with that

Comment: I said when I use mystackpanel.DataContext=this the properties are populated

Comment: Your getter or setter is not proper. So your getting stackoverflow exception

Comment: ok fine let me post it

Comment: public string Mobile_Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

Comment: I have debugged this the exception occurs due to the page.resources

Comment: Okay. Property declaration is proper. Try this instead of page.resources. Give a name to you page element. Then use this binding for stackpanel dstacontext. {Binding ElementName=pagename,Path = DataContext}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108017/discussion-between-mohit-and-archana).

Comment: Better solution is use View Model for binding. Don't declare properties inside code behind. Do it in view model. Then set DataContext of page to view model in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of page.resources. Give a name to your page element. Then use this binding for stackpanel datacontext.

```
 {Binding ElementName=pagename,Path = DataContext}
```